# contains(int aData) with Recursion Linked List Java

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I am having problems trying to check if a value is in a linked list or not using recursion. The values in the linked list are between 0 and 5. If the value is in the linked list, the method should return true. However, I am getting wild answers across the board if the value is indeed in the linked list. Some numbers will return false, and some will return true. I am not sure why it is doing this. Thanks!

```
public boolean contains(int aData)
{
    Node currentNode = firstNode;
    if(currentNode == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(currentNode.data == aData) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will return `true` only if the first node contains the value.

Comment: As @immibis says, you're only checking the first node. Think about how you would perform this check on _all_ nodes in the list?  Hint: you will need another helper method to do this recursively.

Comment: Where's the recursion? And don't guess, debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking one node (the first node). You're going to be needing something like this:

```
public boolean contains(int aData, Node node)
{
    Node currentNode = node;
    // base case; if this node is null, return false
    if(currentNode == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // if this node contains the data, return true, otherwise, check next nodes.
    if(currentNode.data == aData) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return contains(aData, currentNode.next);
    }
}
```

You can call the above function starting with the head node

```
contains(5, headNode);
```

and it will run through your entire list until either a) it finds the data, or b) it has exhausted all options and the data was not found.

Comment: This should not compile. It does not have a return statement if all the `if` statements fail.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this? Thank you!

Comment: @keyser sprinter caught the error, where i fixed it. Can downvoter please explain downvote?

Comment: Don't see anything wrong, so +1. The last statement can be reduced to `return currentNode.data == aData || contains(aData, currentNode.next);`. You could actually make this entire thing one line, but that would be gre-e-easy.

Comment: I thought so. And regarding the downvote: Two of you are doing this guy's homework. Since the code didn't even contain any recursion it's not the time to provide copy-paste code. Note that I'm not criticizing your answer per se and plan to undo the downvote :)

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try to remember not to provide copy/paste code next time.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, you are not using recursion and are only checking the first Node. If you want to use recursion, you'll need to call the `contains` method from within the contains method, which you are not currently doing. Even if you were to simply call it at the end of the method as it stands now, it still wouldn't do anything - think about how you might rewrite it if the method started:

```
public boolean contains(int aData, Node nodeToCheck)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion has a very well defined form that is used in almost all cases. Essentially the form is:

```
type method(context) {
    if (one of the base cases holds)
        return appropriate base value
    else
        for each possible simpler context
            return method(simpler context);
}
```

This works by progressively breaking the problem down into smaller pieces until the problem is so simple it has an obvious answer (i.e. the base case). The key to using recursion is to ask yourself 'in what situations is the answer obvious?' (i.e. the base cases) and 'when the answer isn't obvious how can I simplify the situation to make it more obvious?'. Don't start coding until you can answer those questions!

In your case you have 2 base cases: you've reached the end of your list or you have found the value. If neither of those cases hold then try again in a simpler context. In your case there's only one simpler context: a shorter list.

Putting all that together you have:

```
public boolean contains(Node node, int data) {
    if (node == null)
        return false;
    else if (node.value == data)
        return true;
    else
        return contains(node.next, data);
}
```